# Is the 3D-matching still NP-complete if all elements occur in exactly three triples?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

The 3D-matching problem is known to be NP-complete even if all elements occur at most three times (see Garey&Johnson). My question: Is it also NP-complete if all elements occur in **exactly** three triples?

The 3D-matching is defined as follows: Let $W, X, Y$ be disjoint sets with $|W|=|X|=|Y| = q$. Let $M \subset W \times X \times Y$. Is there a subset $M^\prime \subset M$ with $|M^\prime| = q$ such that all elements are disjoint in each coordinate? That means, each element in $W,X$ and $Y$ occurs exactly once in $M^\prime$.

The bounded version means, that each element in $W,X$ and $Y$ occurs in at most three triples in $M$. My question asks for the case where each element occurs in exactly three triples in $M$.